# adding animation to an access form - front end

Tags: sql, vba

I am Learning how to create dynamic Access Databases using VBA code and SQL.   One of my big "pet peaves" is that the user interface is slick and very professional looking.

I am looking for some tecniques in cosmetic touch ups to make the user interface more professional looking. For example, i would like it so that when the user clicks on a button to activate a sub form which is hidden, that the form appears with a bit of "smoothed animation" such as and exploding transition-type effect instead of the standard hard visual appearance of the form which is the standard.

Any advice on what may be available will be very appreciated.
Thank you,
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can not be done within Access, it's not designed for that.  Access is a database application that comes packaged with Office.  It's not going to provide any crazy out-of-the-box animation, it's just not meant for that.  It's meant to be a very simple, stripped down database application.

It is **somewhat** feasable that you could create animations in a 3rd party app (such as Adobe AfterEffects) and have those animations run prior to the form opening, similar to how one would create motion menus for DVDs.

Comment: thanks, just to be clear, im certainly not lookgin for razzle dazzle type stuff i just want my hidden sub forms to appear in a manner more "soft" when i activate them..  kind like when you activate a sized form it appears with a bit of smoothness...

Comment: @MarcheseIlChihuahua To second Johnny's answer, Access is a simple environment centered around deploying simple data apps quickly.  VBA doesn't have the power of VB.NET and the COM interfaces exposed by Access to VBA don't include many graphical properties.  It's possible to "fake" some of the effects you might desire on the form area itself, but almost definitely not for window transitions (show, maximize, minimize, etc.).  In any case, you'd have to roll them yourself.  If you really need that functionality, move to a "real" platform such as .NET and SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks gentlemen.U R a big help!!  @ Blackhawk - In your opion, given that I use Access kind of "under cover" at work where its functionality helps me solve alot of analytical type problems for me and my colleagues, but database development/architechture is not officially part of my job responsibilities and that my colleagues (and boss) have no interaction with databases whatsover, in your opinion would the endeavor of Learning something such as VB.NET be feasible without taking away too much time at work or stirring up too much attention ??

Answer (score 2):

You could put a bunch of small animated graphics (like lights on a Christmas tree or tiny arrows) all around the sub-form and time it to display for a short while.

Answer (score 0):

yes that Exploding animation is available for MSAcess I use to use it long ago with VBA code and you can even remove the window handle for the form, unfortunately I can not find that code right now, which i want ot use on a new app I am making.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34041538)